# Is ngx translate capable of matching a key based on a SQLesque `LIKE` comparison, or at least a string.startsWith() type comparison?

Tags: angular, typescript, yaml, sql-like, ngx-translate

Our project implements ngx translate to provide translation functionality for the app.

In this case, I need to use it for some machine configuration data rather than a true "language".

To be more specific, I am converting a slew of XML definitions to yaml, but I ran into a few cases like this (notice the MACHINE_MODEL ISLIKE 470*):

```
<ENTRY DESC="OG 470">
    <CRITERIA>
        <CONDGROUP COMBINE="AND">
           <CONDITION NAME="MACHINE_VENDOR" OP="EQ">OG</CONDITION>
           <CONDITION NAME="MACHINE_TYPE" OP="EQ">OGSERIES</CONDITION>
           <CONDITION NAME="MACHINE_MODEL" OP="ISLIKE">470*</CONDITION>
        </CONDGROUP>
    </CRITERIA>
    <PARAMS>
        <PARAMLIST NAME="DEVICES">
        .
        .
        .
```

I am aware of the anchor/alias capability of yaml and suggested using it something like this:

```
'OG':
    '4700': &OG4700Series
        config:
            .
            .
            .
    '4701': *OG4700Series
    '4702': *OG4700Series
    '4750': *OG4700Series
```

However, product management want to implement the wildcard functionality.  Is there a good way to do this in .yaml, or should I start trying to roll my own solution by somehow adding another element to the array of keys that gets passed in for the translate service to try?

Comment: Do you want to use it in the component template (using `translate` pipe) or component class using `instant`/`get` functions?

Comment: @AmerYousuf not in the template, in the typescript with instant, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngx-translate` doesn't support this type of `comparison` by default, but it provides a way to customize the default `parser` ([TranslateDefaultParser](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/74148b74a2c0e0688324ac140a87e5f8ffda2fa8/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.parser.ts#L23)) by implementing your own `parser` to use it instead of the default one.

If you take a look at the `TranslateDefaultParser`, you can notice that [getValue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/74148b74a2c0e0688324ac140a87e5f8ffda2fa8/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/lib/translate.parser.ts#L41) function is used to resolve the passed `key`/`keys` and get the proper value of it from the provided translation:

```js
getValue(target: any, key: string): any {
  let keys = typeof key === 'string' ? key.split('.') : [key];
  key = '';
  do {
    key += keys.shift();
    if (isDefined(target) && isDefined(target[key]) && (typeof target[key] === 'object' || !keys.length)) {
      target = target[key];
      key = '';
    } else if (!keys.length) {
      target = undefined;
    } else {
      key += '.';
    }
  } while (keys.length);

  return target;
}
```

So you can create your own `parser` class by extending the `TranslateDefaultParser` class and overriding the `getValue` function to implement the required `comparison`:

```js
export class TranslateCustomParser extends TranslateDefaultParser {
  /** Gets a value from an object by composed key
   * parser.getValue({ key1: { keyA: 'valueI' }}, 'key1.keyA') ==> 'valueI'
   * @param target the translation object that contains all the keys and values.
   * @param key the passed key from instant/get function or to `translate` pipe.
   */
  getValue(target: any, key: string) {
    // here you can implement the custom `comparison` you need, then return the proper value.
  }
}
```

Then you can configure the `TranslateModule` to use it instead of the default one:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild({
      parser: {
        provide: TranslateParser,
        useClass: TranslateCustomParser,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

Now, when you call `instant`/`get` functions from `TranslateService` or use the `translate` pipe, to get the translation of a specific key, the value will be returned by the proper key using the new parser's `getValue` function.